# React Enzyme with mount() showing element from parent's .html() but doesn't find element with .find()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Using `React`+`Redux` with `Enzyme` for testing (running on `Jest`), I can't find an element when looking for it with `Enzyme`'s [find()](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html). I'm seeing the component being rendered in the html.

I am using full DOM rendering using `Enzyme`'s `mount()`, 
tried searching by other selectors such as `id`, `className`... etc. - same behaviour for all selectors

```
// Feed.js
const arr = ['hhh', 'kkk'];

const Feed = ({posts}) => (
  <div className={s.rightSide}>
    <div data-hook="ziv-is-there">There</div>
    {arr.map(s => (
      <div key={s} data-hook="ziv-is-everywhere">
        {s}
      </div>
    ))}
    {posts.map((post, i) => (
      <div className="ziv-ziv" data-hook="ziv-is-here" key={post.id}>
        {i}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

describe('Feed component', () => {
  function setup(initialState) {
    const props = {
        posts: [{id: 123, title: 'hey'}]
    };
    const store = storeCreator(initialState);
    const componentWrapper = mount(
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18next.init(i18nData)}>
            <Feed store={store} {...props} />
        </I18nextProvider>
    );
    return {
      props,
      store,
      componentWrapper,
    };
  }

   test('renders feed posts', () => {
      const { componentWrapper } = setup();

      expect(componentWrapper.exists()).toBe(true);

      console.log(componentWrapper.html());
      // prints
      /*
      <div class="rightSide">
          <div data-hook="ziv-is-there">There</div>
          <div data-hook="ziv-is-everywhere">hhh</div>
          <div data-hook="ziv-is-everywhere">kkk</div>
          <div class="ziv-ziv" data-hook="ziv-is-here">0</div>
      </div>
      */
      expect(componentWrapper.find('[data-hook="ziv-is-everywhere"]').exists()).toBe(true); // succeeds
      expect(componentWrapper.find('[data-hook="ziv-is-there"]').exists()).toBe(true); // succeeds
      expect(componentWrapper.find('[data-hook="ziv-is-here"]').exists()).toBe(true); // fails
    });
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: There are no `ForumList` and `ForumPost` in the code you posted. It's unknown how they work. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @estus - I've extracted from the main component into its children to make it clearer

Comment: There's no such problem in general because nested element would be found, so it's specific to your case. What is `ForumList`?  Please, provide all relevant code, it's impossible to provide a precise answer otherwise. MCVE is a requirement for SO questions.

Comment: @estus edited. Thanks!

Comment: What is logged when you `console.log(componentWrapper.debug());`

Comment: This isn't MCVE. The code you posted is expected to work and it works, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xuhlfy . Whatever it is, it's specific to things you didn't show. What's `store`? Is it Redux store? Blame it on the way you connected the component to Redux then.

Comment: I don't see this `[data-hook]` how come?
`<I18nextProvider i18n={{...}}>
            <Feed store={{...}} i18nLoadedAt={{...}} t={[Function: fixedT]} i18n={{...}} posts={{...}}>
              <div className="rightSide">
                <div data-hook="ziv-is-there">
                  There
                </div>
                <div data-hook="ziv-is-everywhere">
                  hhh
                </div>
                <div data-hook="ziv-is-everywhere">
                  kkk
                </div>
              </div>
            </Feed>
    </I18nextProvider>`

Comment: @estus here is my store creation, and yes - redux, nothing too odd here:
`const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory({ basename: window.__BASEURL__ }); //history
export const storeCreator = (initialState, history) =>
  createStore(// redux
    connectRouter(history)(rootReducer), //connected-react-router
    initialState,
    compose( // redux
      applyMiddleware(
        routerMiddleware(history), //connected-react-router
        thunk.withExtraArgument(services()), //redux-thunk
      ),
    ),
  );`

Comment: Please, provide a way to replicate the problem, otherwise it's impossible to help with your case. You can use Stackblitz link above as a starter if you wish.

Comment: @estus so it is caused by one of my `redux-thunk` actions, here is the code, any idea why its getting a mess (in both options I see the reducer gets updated and second rendering of the component)
`const loadPosts = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await Promise.resolve({
    data: [
      {
        id: '123',
        title: 'something',
      },
    ],
  }); // async - not working.
  const response = { data: [{ posts: { id: 123, title: 'something' } }] }; // sync - working
  dispatch(postsLoaded(response.data));
};`

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly this thunk prevents a component from correctly using `find`, while `html` works. But it dorsn't seem like a good idea to test a component with unmocked thunk any way. This odd problem is an example of what happens when we don't isolate units in unit tests. Thunks aren't great for testing. I'd suggest to stub it and test separately.

Comment: @estus FYI, when I'm using just `react-dom/test-utils` everything works like a charm. from searching the net I see more examples of developers complaining about differences between `enzyme`'s `html()` and `debug()` results. maybe something there?

Comment: I'm positive that it does. My point that Enzyme already does tricky things to make it work like it works that are not always compliant with expected behaviour or React own renders. Increasing the complexity of tested unit makes it even more unpredictable which isn't a good thing for a test.

Comment: Bummer no one ever figured this out. But it seems like the answer is "switch to React Testing Library."